# How to get the MailItem belonging to a read receipt (ReportItem) via Outlook automation

Tags: automation, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, mailitem

Outlook stores read receipts as `ReportItem` objects.

Is it possible to get an `ID` or some details of the original message belonging to a given read receipt? I've looked through the [properties of the `ReportItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176769%28v=office.12%29.aspx) object but I'm lost.

Since read receipts come in different forms, I wouldn't want to process the body of the receipt programmatically - instead I'm looking to get it from Outlook if it's possible.

**Note**: the solution should work from at least Outlook 2003 to new versions.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the only link between the `ReportItem` and the source `MailItem` is the [`ConversationIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869024.aspx) and [`ConversationTopic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860352.aspx). This is what Outlook uses to link together the read receipt messages with the related source `MailItem`. You just need to [filter by the `ConversationTopic`](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1714) and then [use the first 44 chars of the `ConversationIndex` to identify the original source `MailItem`](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_23334181.html).

#### Sample Conversation Indexes

**Source Index**:  `01CDC1C35624E2A7BD18CF8C439CA73B62A052922657` 
**Receipt Index**: `01CDC1C35624E2A7BD18CF8C439CA73B62A0529226570000012862`

You can use `Items.Restrict` to reduce the items to a specific DASL filter

#### **DASL Search:**

`[ConversationTopic] = 'read receipt ConversationTopic here'`

#### Locating ReportItem's parent MailItem

```cs
Outlook.MailItem source = FindReadReceiptSourceMessage(ri);
string entryID = source.EntryID;
// ...
public static Outlook.MailItem FindReadReceiptSourceMessage(Outlook.ReportItem readReceipt) 
{
    Outlook.Folder inbox = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Outlook.Folder;
    string sourceIndex = readReceipt.ConversationIndex.Substring(0, 44);
    string topicFilter = string.Format("[ConversationTopic] = '{0}'", readReceipt.ConversationTopic);
    Outlook.Items topicItems = inbox.Items.Restrict(topicFilter);
    return topicItems.OfType<Outlook.MailItem>().Where(c=>c.ConversationIndex.Equals(sourceIndex)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean: "You just need to filter by the ConversationTopic and then use the first 44 chars of the ConversationIndex to identify the original source MailItem."

But I think we only filter by the first 44 chars of the ConversationIndex. Because if there are 2 emails have same ConversationTopic then we are no need to filter with ConversationTopic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Remdemption library on your item 'myitem'.  In my opinion better than the above

```
    If vs_sender = "" Then 'read receipts
            Set objSMail = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
            objSMail.item = myitem
            vs_sender = objSMail.SenderEmailAddress
            vs_recipient = myitem.Recipients(1).Address
            Set objSMail = Nothing
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to compare these common fields,

1. Compare Message-ID from the original message & In-Reply-To from Read Receipts, values should be same.
2. Text from Subject field from original message repeats Subject field in Read Receipts message.